# padding pandas dataframe upsampling with cyclic data

Tags: python, pandas

I am working with a pandas dataframe which I load this way:

```
data = pd.read_csv("population_stats.txt", sep=" ", header=None)

      0    1    2
0   100  200   300
1   400  500   600
2   700  800   900
3   420  320   652
4   125  258   852
```

I would like to pad this with cylic data, meaning, reapeating the data till a constant 256 row count. So, the final dataframe looking:

```
      0    1    2
0   100  200   300
1   400  500   600
2   700  800   900
3   420  320   652
4   125  258   852
5   100  200   300
6   400  500   600
7   700  800   900
8   420  320   652
9   125  258   852
10   100  200   300
11   400  500   600
12   700  800   900
13   420  320   652
14   125  258   852
--   ..   ..   ..
256  <>   <>   <>
```

I was wondering if there was a quick pandas trick to do this, which would avoid writing any pure python loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

larger = np.tile(df, (52,1)) # use np.tile to repeat the df
# the repeated version needs clipping to 256 rows as it has more than that
clipped = pd.DataFrame(larger).head(256)
```

Comment: what does `(52,1) do please?

Comment: It tells np.tile() how many times to repeat the dataframe in each axis so 52 times going down and 1 time going across. See the documentation [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html).